# How to set the value from one column to another in the same row by scala-slick

Tags: scala, slick

[example code](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/v3.3.1/doc/code/LiftedEmbedding.scala#L384-L387)
In my case:

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

case class User(id: Option[Int], vid: Int, first: String, last: String)

  class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def vid = column[Int]("vid")
    def first = column[String]("first")
    def last = column[String]("last")
    def * = (id.?, vid, first, last) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  }
  val users = TableQuery[Users]

  def usersForInsert = users.map(u => (u.vid, u.first, u.last).shaped <>
    ({t => User(None, t._1, t._2, t._3)}, {(u: User) => Some((u.vid, u.first, u.last))}))

//#insert vid value
   val userWithId =
     (users returning users.map(_.id)
        into ((user,id) => user.copy(id=Some(id)))

     //Here, I wonder how to replace the value of vid by id
     ) += User(None, 4, "Stefan", "Zeiger")
//#insert

    val userWithIdRes = Await.result(db.run(users.schema.create >> userWithId), Duration.Inf)
    println(userWithIdRes)
```

I have tried some ways, but always get errors while compiling and running.
Thank you for reading the beginning level question of scala-slick

Comment: Hello L.Ben - welcome to Slick. Your question contains a lot of code. Perhaps you can edit it down to show what you want to do, what errors you get, or possibly what kind of SQL you want to execute. That may make it easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: THX@RichardDallaway, I'm learning 'lift' via 'lif cookbook' too. :). Scala is so amazing and interesting, but a little difficult for beginner of program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you defined `User.id` like `AutoInc` you can't have a value on insert action. It will be generated by DB system. So what you can do first insert and get id then update the column that you want. This can be done something like this:

```scala
val newUserId: Future[Int] =
    for {
      userId <- db.run(
        (users returning users.map(_.id)) += User(None, 0, "Stefan", "Zeiger")
      )
      _ <- db.run(users.filter(_.id === userId).map(_.vid).update(userId))
    } yield userId
```

However, there is an extra call to DB. This can lead to performance issue in future where you might have fast writes. If it's just for learning purposes yes it's doable, but in real code bases it's better to design in a different way. For exmaple `vid` always has the same value as `id`, so you can use `vid` in application level, but not necessarily in db.

Comment: THX@Bob, This is one solution that only for learning as you said, but is helpful for understanding scala and slick.

Comment: @L.Ben you can accept my answer if you are satisfied with it

Comment: Well...It did help me in some places